# Zooming for a Graphics2D object

Tags: java, graphics

I currently have a Graphics2D object which is acting as a perpendicular coordinate system(regular x-y system). I want to implement zooming which acts on a mouse listener. I have thought of getting a *BufferedImage* with **Robot** Class and then using **PixelGrabber** to zoom in, but wondered if I can directly work with Graphics2D without using **Image** objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can use an AffineTransform ([AffineTransform.getScaleInstance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) in particular) to scale all aspects of a graphics context.  You could use that to either zoom in (create a larger scale) or zoom out (use a scale less than 1).  I have [a blog post that shows how to use AffineTransforms for things like rotation and translation](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/how-to-make-a-solar-system-introduction-to-affine-transformations-and-java-2d/), and not so much scaling, but it's a similar principle.  You'll have to be mindful of how scaling the graphics context affects things like selection, listeners, etc.  (Your coordinate system for the panel will need to be converted into the coordinate system for the graphics context in order to correctly select/click on objects in the scaled graphics context.)